# Navigation Bar - Highlight background if active URL?

Tags: html, css, navigation

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

We have a navigation bar as standard on magento, I have managed to duplicate this (through copying and editting bits of html/css) and place it below the original navigation bar - so we effectively have 2.

The original navigation bar works through magento code and identifies if a category URL is active then the navigation bar for that category is highlighted in red.

I now want to try and replicate this, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am doing this locally so can't give a website link unfortunately.

HTML:

```
 <div class="nav-container2">
    <ul id="nav2">
        <li class="downloads"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/foscamsite/downloads" id="Downloads"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>
        <li class="forum"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/foscamsite/forum" id="Forum"><span>Forum</span></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-container2 { width:940px; margin:auto; height:30px;}
    #nav2 { width:547px; height:40px; float:right; margin:1px 0 0 0; font-size:105%; background:url(../images/bg-nav.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc; }
    #nav2 li { position:relative; text-align:left; }
    #nav2 li.over { z-index:998; }
    #nav2 a,
    #nav2 a:hover { display:block; line-height:1.3em; text-decoration:none; }
    #nav2 span { display:block; cursor:pointer; white-space:nowrap; }
    #nav2 li ul span {white-space:normal; }
    #nav2 ul li.parent a { background:url(../images/bkg_nav2.gif) 100% 100% no-repeat; }
    #nav2 ul li.parent li a { background-image:none; }
    #nav2 li { float:left; margin:0 1px 0 0; }
    #nav2 li.active a { background:url(../images/bg-nav-hover.png) 0 0 repeat-x; color:#fff; }
    #nav2 a { float:left; padding:12px 14px 11px; color:#787878; font-size:105%;  }
    #nav2 li.over a,
    #nav2 a:hover { background:url(../images/bg-nav-hover.png) 0 0 repeat-x; color:#fff; }
```

Got a feeling some of this CSS isn't needed, just not where to start in terms of modifying it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this not work? What is it that you want help with?

Comment: This works in the sense it highlights on hover. However it isn't working to remain highlighted if the URL is active.

I.E if I'm on www.website.com/downloads , I'd like the 'Downloads' tab to remain active :).

Comment: Based on the class name, I'd say that's supposed to be #nav2 li.active a - is the image ../images/bg-nav-hover.png valid?

Comment: Yes, as it's the same image for hover and active, and hover works fine :). Do I not need to link li class to CSS somehow or is that not needed?

Comment: The CSS will only display that image when the class "active" has been added to the li - so it should look like <li class="downloads active"> or <li class="forum active"> when in the appropriate state. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, but then it is active all the time. Is there a way of adding (possibly some php) to check if the URL is active or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, that will be handled by the PHP but I'm not that familiar with Gentoo so I can't say exactly how I'm afraid. Your CSS is fine anyway, you just need to work out why the class "active" isn't being added - which will be a PHP thing.

Comment: <?php if ():?> active<?php endif;?>  Just got to work out what to put in the brackets then

Comment: OK, I assumed your menus were being generated through some kind of Gentoo-specific code. Gimme a sec & I'll post you a vanilla PHP solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note I've taken off the server address & made the URLs relative so hopefully it will make it simpler to migrate to the live server:

```
<?php

echo "<div class=\"nav-container2\">\n";
echo "<ul id=\"nav2\">\n";
echo "<li class=\"downloads";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/foscamsite/downloads") echo " active";
echo "\"><a href=\"/foscamsite/downloads\" id=\"Downloads\"><span>Downloads</span></a></li>\n";
echo "<li class=\"forum";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/foscamsite/forum") echo " active";
echo "\"><a href=\"/foscamsite/forum\" id=\"Forum\"><span>Forum</span></a></li>\n";
echo "</ul>\n";
echo "</div>\n";

?>
```

Comment: ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "x") works perfectly, thank you. Just realised something else doesn't quite work with recent changes so going to need to back peddle a little bit, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to do if you add a php variable above the header and use it for the active states in the navigation.

For example:

```
<?php $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<div class="nav-container2">
<ul id="nav2">
    <li <?php if ($page == 'downloads.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="downloads.php" id="Downloads">     <span>Downloads</span></a></li>
<li <?php if ($page == 'forum.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="forum.php" id="Forum"><span>Forum</span></a></li>
```

Hope this helps